# Почему стих — белый?

Tags: этимология

Почему бессмысленный шум называют, я еще могу понять: белый цвет соединяет в себе все остальные, как и белый шум вбирает в себя все шумы. Но почему стих без рифмы называют белым?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь белый в значении "не заполненный текстом, чистый (о листе бумаги)".Этот стих по сравнению с рифмованным "белый": окончания, где обычно помещается созвучие (рифма), остаются в звуковом отношении незаполненными, чистыми ("белыми"). Это не означает хаотической неорганизованности окончаний в них. Они подвергаются отбору, например, мужские- с ударением на последнем слоге, женские- на предпоследнем, дактилические- на третьем слоге от конца. Чаще сочетаются два вида окончаний.